# How to create a JsonNode chaining two arrays?

Tags: java, json, jackson, method-chaining

I'm building a complex JSON object with Jackson and I want to structure the code to display the JSON structure clearly, so I'm trying to use the JsonNode API with chained `with`, `put` and `set` methods. At one place inside all this chained stuff I need to add two arrays one after the other. Here's a simplified excerpt:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectNode json = new ObjectNode(JsonNodeFactory.instance);
json.with("data")
    .set("array1", arrayNode1)
    .set("array2", arrayNode1);
```

I want it to create this JSON:

```
{
    "data": {
        "array1": [...],
        "array2": [...]
    }
}
```

First `set` is fine because it's called on `ObjectNode`. The problem is it returns `JsonNode`, which doesn't have a `set` method, and so the second `set` call results in compilation error.

How can I chain setting two arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't really improve readability that much, but if you have Guava on the classpath, you can do the following:

```
ObjectNode json = new ObjectNode(JsonNodeFactory.instance);
json.with("data")
    .setAll(ImmutableMap.of(
        "array1", arraynode1, 
        "array2", arraynode2));
```

`setAll` returns the object node.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it's a way to do it, thanks. Although I'm wondering why Jackson restricts JsonNode's API this way.

Comment: It's a flaw in the API where it returns a JsonNode instead of an ObjectNode and thus breaks chaining but this behavior can't be "fixed" directly without breaking backward compatibility: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37543058/using-jackson-s-objectnode-putobject-for-method-chaining